# How to move a versioned file to unversioned in Pycharm?

Tags: git

I accidentally added some unversioned files to local changelist and now want to move them back to unversioned changelist.

I can do it hard way - delete file.
Is there a soft way? :)
Thaks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the git command line, you would run the following if you have not committed.

```
git reset File_To_Unstage
```

It looks like PyCharm has a [menu option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/git-reset-dialog.html) for this.

Both of these options will remove the file from the staging area without removing it from the working directory.

Comment: Menu option is not good for me, I don't want to "play" with rest of the files.

Comment: I would recommend just doing it from the git command line in that case.  Just run reset on all the files which you accidentally added and they will be unstaged.

Comment: Maybe he wants ```untrack``` files, not ```reset```.